# Laravel Query Builder Statement return no result, but sql statement does

Tags: sql, laravel

**Laravel Query Builder**

```
     $data = CustomerPrepaid
            ::join('pos_sales', 'customer_prepaid.customer_id', '=', 'pos_sales.customer_id')
            ->join('pos_sales_product', 'pos_sales.pos_sales_code', '=', 'pos_sales_product.pos_sales_code')
            ->where('pos_sales_product.product_id', 'customer_prepaid.product_id')
            ->select('customer_prepaid.customer_id', 'customer_prepaid.created_at',
            'pos_sales_product.pos_sales_product_code as reference_no', 

'customer_prepaid.product_id', 'customer_prepaid.balance', 
        'last_used', 'expiry_date', 'customer_prepaid.amount as price')
        ->offset(($page-1)*$limit)->limit($limit)->get();
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT customer_prepaid.customer_id, customer_prepaid.created_at as purchase_date,
pos_sales_product.pos_sales_product_code as reference_no, customer_prepaid.product_id, 
customer_prepaid.balance, customer_prepaid.amount*customer_prepaid.balance as value, 
last_used, expiry_date, customer_prepaid.amount as price,
customer_prepaid.amount*customer_prepaid.balance as total
FROM customer_prepaid
JOIN pos_sales ON customer_prepaid.customer_id = pos_sales.customer_id
JOIN pos_sales_product ON pos_sales.pos_sales_code = pos_sales_product.pos_sales_code
WHERE pos_sales_product.product_id = customer_prepaid.product_id
```

The resulting SQL executed on the server returns the right result, but I get no eloquent result, why might that be?

Comment: Did you check the SQL generated by the Query Builder using ->toSql() instead of ->offset(($pag..... ?

Comment: After checked with toSql(),I get this result.
https://puu.sh/z70cw/4a4cddc975.png

Comment: Could it be `$page` is giving you paged result? Have you tried the query builder without `offset` and `limit`?

Comment: I test already remove offset(), but get no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh gosh, took me forever to realize you misused `->where`.

Change your `->where` to `->whereColumn`:

```
$data = CustomerPrepaid
        ::join('pos_sales', 'customer_prepaid.customer_id', '=', 'pos_sales.customer_id')
        ->join('pos_sales_product', 'pos_sales.pos_sales_code', '=', 'pos_sales_product.pos_sales_code')
        ->whereColumn('pos_sales_product.product_id', 'customer_prepaid.product_id')
        ->select(
            'customer_prepaid.customer_id',
            'customer_prepaid.created_at',
            'pos_sales_product.pos_sales_product_code as reference_no',
            'customer_prepaid.product_id', 'customer_prepaid.balance',
            'last_used', 'expiry_date', 'customer_prepaid.amount as price'
        )
        ->offset(($page-1)*$limit)
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
```

You have to use `whereColumn` instead of `where` to make column comparison. Else it's expecting a third parameter `value` to be set.

Check the documentation on how to use `whereColumn`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Thanks you sir. like that ok :)